Static IP Assigned by ISP is in Private Range (172.168.4.50) and Not Reachable from Outside
Issue Description:
I am trying to set up file transfer between my Raspberry Pi and an Ubuntu desktop using a FastAPI server. Here’s my setup:

FastAPI Server Setup:

Deployed FastAPI on the Ubuntu desktop.
The server listens on port 2121.


Static IP Setup:

My ISP assigned me the static IP 172.168.4.50 (as confirmed via the router settings).
Enabled port forwarding on my router for port 2121 to the local IP of the Ubuntu desktop.


Testing the Setup:

The FastAPI server is reachable locally (e.g., http://localhost:2121/).
However, when I try to access http://172.168.4.50:2121/ from outside the network, the request fails.


Troubleshooting Steps Taken:

Verified port forwarding rules on the router.
Checked that the FastAPI server is running and listening on the correct port.
Tested accessibility by temporarily disabling the firewall on the Ubuntu desktop.




Concern:
After some research, I realized that 172.168.4.50 falls within the private IP range (172.16.0.0 to 172.31.255.255). From my understanding, private IPs are not routable on the public internet.

Questions:

Is it possible that my ISP has provided a private static IP instead of a public static IP?
If so, does this mean the API will not be accessible over the internet, even with port forwarding enabled?
Should I ask my ISP to assign a public-facing static IP instead?


System Details:

Server OS: Ubuntu Desktop
ISP-Provided Static IP: 172.168.4.50
Port Forwarded: 2121
FastAPI: Python-based API server


Expected Behavior:
The API should be accessible from anywhere using the ISP-assigned static IP and port 2121.

Actual Behavior:
Requests to http://172.168.4.50:2121/endpoint fail and time out, even though port forwarding is configured.
error image

How is that a serverfault question? You chose your ISP, you are behind NAT, that is like "I bought a car, how do I make it fly" level. That said, start learning basics- you can sue a VPN to a VPS (cheap) to route traffic through a public IP, you can use Cloudflare networked Zero Trust to have an incoming HTTP tunnel. Or other solutions.

Voting to close - belongs to Superuser.com

Also, not sure how .168 is between .16 and .31

Check the WAN IP in your router's status page and compare it with the IP shown on a service like WhatIsMyIP.

172.168.4.50 is a public, routable, IP - you're confused - though, it is assigned to Microsoft ... so

I was initially confused about whether the assigned IP address was private or public. After further investigation, I found that the IP address is indeed a private IP address. The router is using Carrier-Grade NAT (CGNAT) for routing purposes, which is why the IP address appears in a private range and is not directly reachable from the internet.

The address given above (172.168.4.50) is a public IP address - I can traceroute around 18 hops before the traceroute dies, private IP's don't get past my router.

Yeah, you're confusing IP address ranges just like your ISP did. The address is not in a private range. Your ISP mistakenly uses it for their CGNAT configuration as if it were a private range (confusing 172.16 + 192.168 = 172.168), but it's literally not a private range.


Is it possible that my ISP has provided a private static IP instead of a public static IP?

In a way, yes. That's very common among residential ISPs (and increasingly common even for smaller business plans) as ISPs just run out of IPv4 addresses and have no way to obtain more.
Although your ISP used the wrong range (as others have mentioned, the ISP got two different private IP ranges mixed up, or perhaps mistyped "172.16" as "172.168", and ended up using a chunk of Microsoft's public address space instead) but the end result is functionally the same: the address you have is not routed to you over the Internet, and is only functional within the ISP's network.
(For actually private addresses, the Internet has no routes at all. For "172.168", the Internet does have a route, but in a completely different direction – towards Microsoft's Azure network, which legitimately owns those addresses – and the end result is the same, i.e. packets from other ISPs have no chance of reaching you. In both cases, your outgoing Internet access only works because the ISP will SNAT all packets to one of their actually public addresses.)

If so, does this mean the API will not be accessible over the internet, even with port forwarding enabled?

Yes.

Should I ask my ISP to assign a public-facing static IP instead?

Yes.

Thanks for answering this I'll surely talk to ISP about this
